# postgres set start sequence value in laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I am setting sequence in laravel migration

```
Schema::create('businesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('business_id');
            $table->string('business_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

DB::select("select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('businesses', 'business_id'), 1000000000 )");
```

After migration when i am checking

```
select currval('businesses_business_id_seq');
//It returning ERROR:  currval of sequence "businesses_business_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
```

If i run below same query after migration in `laravel tinker` or in `seeder` then its work.

```
DB::select("select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('businesses', 'business_id'), 1000000000 )");
```

So the main question is that why `DB::select("select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('businesses', 'business_id'), 1000000000 )")` not working at the time of migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `sequence`**

```
 $table->id()->from('100000');
```

`->from($integer)` it set the starting value of an auto-incrementing field

**Using `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` constraint**

```
$table->id()->generatedAs('START WITH 100000');
```

`->generatedAs($expression)` it create an identity column with specified sequence options (PostgreSQL)